# Where does the OpenGL drawing code go in cross platform projects? Planning my engine code

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es

I am trying to develop a cross-platform app. I am going to write the iOS version with as much C++ as possible then later on use that same C++ code on Android. If I update the C++ code I can just recompile on the other platform. I plan to be developing this entirely in XCode focusing on iOS development then take the C++ files over to my Android project.

I am trying to plan out the graphics engine I am writing, but I am not sure what code I should put inside of the C++ section and what code should go in the platform specific section.

For example, once an OpenGL ES context is made in Java or Swift code can C++ code make draw calls using that context, or is there a problem with that? Should my drawing code be in the C++ section or the platform specific section? Ideally, I would like the only platform-specific code to be nuances about file saving, sending touch event id and location, getting device resolution. However, I am not sure how realistic that is.

Since I will be using multi-threading in the c++ code do I have to worry about multithreading working differently on Android than in iOS?

Also would there be any speed loss on either iOS or Android because of this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context creation calls for iOS and Android are completely orthogonal. iOS you generally use the [`CAEAGLLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/caeagllayer)/[`EAGLContext`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/opengles/eaglcontext) objects, which are Apple proprietary APIs. On Android, you generally use the [EGL](https://www.khronos.org/egl) functions, which are portable to multiple platforms. Frequently, on Android the [`GLSurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) helper classes are used, which handles most of the EGL interface calls for you, but that's not specifically required. There are many tutorials in the internet showing how to set this up on both platforms.

There are language bindings to create contexts in Objective-C/C++ and Swift on iOS, and in Java or C/C++ in Android. A context created in any language is compatible with draw calls made in C/C++ (the reverse is also true).

While the base OpenGL ES API is identical between the two platforms, they will differ in the extensions that they provide. Apple has given a [specific list](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforAppleA7GPUsandLater/BestPracticesforAppleA7GPUsandLater.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH505-DontLinkElementID_4) of the extension they support, whereas Android GPU vendors decide which extensions are available, and there is quite a lot of variance. So, although not explicitly platform specific, you may need some code that deals with different extensions, with fallback rendering paths if an extension is not available. How to organize your code is obviously up to you, but the "drawing" portion of your code could feasibly be put in shared code, with small differences (with the use of `#define`/`#ifdef` preprocessor statements based on the platform).

While the operation of multithreading between iOS and Android are similar, in OpenGL ES (in general), multithreading is a consideration. A thread may only has one OpenGL ES context active at a time (and the functions for setting it are specific between the two platforms), and sharing the context across threads requires synchronization. Generally, OpenGL/ES applications only interact with the context on a single thread (and potentially have other threads do other non-OpenGL work).